# Django gettext <br> tag

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

Thank you for checking my question.

I try to use gettext and serve my django website in another languages.

- I want to add a class to the br tag.
  As shown in ↓, an error does not occur if there is only a br tag,
  `{% trans "I am a student. <br> I am a man."%}`
  But as shown below, if you add a class, an error will occur.
  `{% trans "I am a student. <br class="aaaa"> I am a man."%}`

Could you teach me is there any good solution?

Comment: Use a second translate tag?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many possibilities:

## Use class in wrapped HTML tag, for example `div`:

```
<-- in html -->
<div class="aaaa"> {% trans "I am a student. <br> I am a man."%}</ div>
```

don't forget about css:

```
.aaaa br {
}
```

## you can use `blocktranslate` template tag:

more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#std-templatetag-blocktranslate

## of course, you can use two template tags:

```
<div class="aaaa"> 
{% trans "I am a student."%}
</ div> 
<div class="bbb"> 
{% trans "I am a man."%}
</ div>
```

i don't like the last solution: if first `trans` bounded with second `trans` and they should be translated together.